# Card on File Recurring - Apply a filter to fetched recurring orders

Tags: rules, commerce

With the cardonfile module comes a submodule 'cardonfile_recurring' that provides a rule to charging pending recurring orders.

What I'm trying to achieve: 
I want to filter the list of recurring orders loaded in this rule, 
i want to charge only recurring orders referenced to a recurring entity that has been created from an order that has a payment method that supports cardonfile.

For example let's say i have 2 recurring products, Product A & B, and 2 payments method X (Supports CardOnFile)  & Y (no cardonfile integration for example cash on delivery)
I've ordered Product A and paid using payment method X, and Product B using payment method Y.

After confirming the payments, i get 2 recurring entities C (for A) & D( for B) each Product. I want to charge only recurring orders that are referenced in Recurring entity C.

What i tried to do is to check the first order referenced to this recurring entity and check if it's has been paid using a payment method that supports card on file.

I made this filter as an action:

```
function MODULE_NAME_recurring_rules_action_info() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'rules', 'entity.rules');
  $action = array();
  $action['filter_reccurring'] = array(
    'label' => t('Filter Card On File Recurring Orders'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'value' => array(
        'label' => t('Entity type'),
        'type' => 'list,
        ),
      ),
    'provides' => array(
      'entity_fetched' => array('type' => 'list', 'label' => t('Fetched entity')),
    ),
    'group' => t('MODULE_NAME Recurring'),
  );
 return $action;
}
```

And this is the action callback:

```
     function filter_reccurring($args, $element) {

$return = array();
foreach ($args as $key => $arg) {
    $recurring_entity = commerce_recurring_load_by_order($arg);
    $ent = reset($recurring_entity);
    if (isset($ent->commerce_recurring_order['und'][0])) {
        $rec = entity_load('commerce_order', array($ent->commerce_recurring_order['und'][0]['target_id']));
        $first_order = reset($rec);

        $payment_method = explode('|', $first_order->data['payment_method']);

        $payment_methods = _commerce_cardonfile_capable_payment_methods();

        if (!isset($payment_methods[$payment_method[0]])) {
            unset($args[$key]);
        }
    }
```

//
    }

```
foreach ($args as $arg) {
    $return[] = (int) $arg->order_id;
}

return array('entity_fetched' => $return);
}
```

[image: This is the error i'm getting when i applied the filter]

What am i doing wrong ?